# Can't reach login screen after accidental power loss during an upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, startup

During the upgrade, my computer shut down.

After starting it I see a black screen with `[OK]` sentences with finished tasks after them.
The last one is:

```
[OK] Started GNOME display Manager. 
     Dispatcher Service...ed database.s.pp link was shut down...
```

Do I need to format my computer?
If not, what else can I do?

Comment: Nope, the gnome manager starts, this has nothing to do with grub.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

Then I'd try to restart the upgrade process with

```
do-release-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, try the following:

```
apt-get install -f

dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: TY very much it worked :)

Comment: +1 to compensate for OP's lack thereof.

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful. You might want to click the ACCEPT button now.